# Android Studio: Open phone gallery with image upload button using php/html

Tags: php, android, html, android-studio

basically i created a website than converted it into an app with the help of Android Studio using this guy's blog .... [link]karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/2015/07/… [link]... Since its built on html when i open the app on the mobile the html tag [code]      [/code] does not open up the gallery of the android phone

Comment: What is clearly your problem ? What is your code ?

Comment: basically i created a website than converted it into an app with the help of Android Studio with the help of this guy's blog .... [link]http://karthiktechfreak.blogspot.in/2015/07/profesional-android-webview-application.html [link]... Since its built on html when i open the app on the mobile the html tag [code]  <input type="file" name="pic" > [/code] does not open up the gallery of the android phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your question is not well received but i think that you want to open phone gallery by clicking event.
Am i right?
If it is so then you have to do like this
First of all initialize

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
```

then

```
 your_Click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);


}
        });
```

Comment: Yes thats correct!! I havent asked the question in the right way tho.. But my code is in HTML and PHP

Comment: sure this did not help me.. My file is in php ! any help with that?

Comment: Sorry dear..for php i have no idea.